# How to use BufferedReader to take integers from input and store as objects

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to set up a program that takes user input (ex. '12 20 14 23 08 19'), and creates objects of the class 'Period(int start, int end)'. I would like to store these objects into an array so that I can iterate through them.

```
import java.io.*;

class myCode
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(input);

    //Array for storing period objects
    Period[] array = new Period[];

    //12 20 14 23 08 19

}

public static class Period{

    public int start;
    public int end;

    public Period(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    void printPeriod(){
        System.out.println("Start: " + start);
        System.out.println("End: " + start);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to learn how Streams work? The reason I ask, is because there is an easier method using `Scanner`..

Answer (score 2):

One simple option would be to just split the input string on whitespace, and then populate your array of periods:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = br.readLine();
String[] parts = input.split("\\s+");

Period[] array = new Period[parts.length / 2];
for (int i=0; i < parts.length; i=i+2) {
    int start = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
    int end = Integer.parseInt(parts[i+1]);
    Period period = new Period(start, end);

    array[i/2] = period;
}
```

The logic behind the `for` loop is to take steps of two, and each step, to create and populate a `Period` object.  This `Period` object then gets added to the array at the `i/2` position.